# how can i import a class Product from model.py in Shop app to the cart.py in the Cart pp

Tags: python, django

File "C:\Users\KARIM\Desktop\DjangoShop\online\Cart\cart.py", line 4, in 
from ..Shop.models import Product
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Comment: can you also show the directory structure

Comment: online
  online
    -->settings.py  //   
  Cart
    --->cart.py   //    
  shop
    --->models.py
         ...Product

Answer (score 0):

switch

```
from Shop.models import Product
```

to

```
from online.Shop.models import Product
```

Comment: once i write from online.Shop.models import Product it rise this error:      from online.Shop.models import Product
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'online.Shop'